# Adding meals to list on Worksheet, from UserForm

Tags: performance, vba, excel

As you may know, this is an ongoing thing [1](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/117529/looking-up-ingredients-and-creating-a-shopping-list) [2](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/186775/retrieve-total-and-display-ingredients-of-meal) [3](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/186874/retrieve-remove-duplicates-and-total-ingredients-into-array)

I've created a form that pops up when a user wants to add a new meal to the meal plan.

[image]

The UI is pretty terrible, but what I'm running into is when the `Create Meal` button is pressed, **everything works fine**, but it seems to hang.

It's taking longer than it should. Right now adding a meal takes ***nearly 4 seconds***. I find this ridiculous unless somehow I've hit the limits of VBA, which seems impossible.

The Form Code -

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CloseForm_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub

Public Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Const SELECTION_LIST_DELIMITED As String = "Breakfast,Lunch,Dinner,Snack"
    Const DELIMITER As String = ","
    MealTypeSelection.List = Split(SELECTION_LIST_DELIMITED, DELIMITER)
End Sub

Private Sub IngredientAmtSpin_SpinDown()
    If Not NewIngredientAmount.Value < 2 Then
        NewIngredientAmount.Value = Val(NewIngredientAmount.Value) - 1
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub IngredientAmtSpin_SpinUp()
    NewIngredientAmount.Value = Val(NewIngredientAmount.Value) + 1
End Sub

Private Sub AddIngredient_Click()
    If NewIngredient.Value = vbNullString Or Not IsNumeric(NewIngredientAmount.Value) Then Exit Sub
    If NewIngredientAmount.Value < 1 Then NewIngredientAmount.Value = 1
    Dim ingredient As String
    ingredient = NewIngredient.Value

    Dim IngredientAmount As Long
    IngredientAmount = Int(NewIngredientAmount.Value)

    IngredientList.AddItem ingredient
    IngredientList.List(IngredientList.listCount - 1, 1) = IngredientAmount
    NewIngredient.Value = vbNullString
    NewIngredientAmount.Value = 1
End Sub

Private Sub ClearIngredientList_Click()
    IngredientList.Clear
End Sub

Private Sub CreateMealButton_Click()
    Dim begin As Double
    Dim total As Double
    begin = Timer
    Dim mealType As String

    If MealTypeSelection.Text = vbNullString Then
        MsgBox "Please select a meal type."
        Exit Sub
    Else: mealType = MealTypeSelection.Text
    End If

    If Not NewIngredient.Value = vbNullString Then
        MsgBox "Did you forget to add an ingredient to the list?"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim mealName As String
    mealName = StrConv(MealNameBox.Value, vbProperCase)


    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet

    Select Case mealType
        Case "Breakfast"
            Set targetSheet = wsBreakfast
        Case "Lunch"
            Set targetSheet = wsLunch
        Case "Dinner"
            Set targetSheet = wsDinner
        Case "Snack"
            Set targetSheet = wsSnacks
    End Select


    Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = targetSheet.Cells(targetSheet.Rows.count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

    If MealExists(targetSheet, lastRow, mealName) Then
        MsgBox "Meal name already exists. Meal not created."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Dim listCount As Long
    listCount = IngredientList.listCount
    If listCount = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No ingredients entered"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim listOfIngredients() As String
    ReDim listOfIngredients(1 To listCount, 1)


    Dim index As Long
    For index = LBound(listOfIngredients) To UBound(listOfIngredients)
        listOfIngredients(index, 0) = StrConv(IngredientList.List(index - 1, 0), vbProperCase)
        listOfIngredients(index, 1) = StrConv(IngredientList.List(index - 1, 1), vbProperCase)
    Next

    MakeMeal targetSheet, lastRow + 1, mealName, listOfIngredients
    If KeepActive.Value = True Then
        IngredientList.Clear
        MealNameBox.Value = vbNullString
    Else
        Unload Me
    End If
    total = Round(Timer - begin, 2)
    Debug.Print total
End Sub

Private Function MealExists(ByVal targetSheet As Worksheet, ByVal lastRow As Long, ByVal mealName As String) As Boolean
    MealExists = False
    Dim rowNumber As Long
    For rowNumber = 1 To lastRow
        If targetSheet.Cells(rowNumber, 1) = mealName Then
            MealExists = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function

Private Sub MakeMeal(ByVal targetSheet As Worksheet, ByVal lastRow As Long, ByVal mealName As String, ByVal listOfIngredients As Variant)

    targetSheet.Cells(lastRow, 1) = mealName
    Dim index As Long
    For index = LBound(listOfIngredients) To UBound(listOfIngredients)
        targetSheet.Cells(lastRow + index - 1, 2) = listOfIngredients(index, 0)
        targetSheet.Cells(lastRow + index - 1, 3) = listOfIngredients(index, 1)
    Next
End Sub
```

The part that hangs is the `CreateMealButton_Click()`. I've included the timer. There's a bunch of other code doing other stuff, but none of it interacts with the form.

All the objects' names pretty much describe what they actually are, but the actual book can be [downloaded from github](https://github.com/RaymondWise/Excel-Weekly-Meal-Plan-Shopping-List-Generator/blob/Copy-that-is-not-fully-functioning/Mealplan%20-%20Template.xlsm)

[Experimental branch](https://github.com/RaymondWise/Excel-Weekly-Meal-Plan-Shopping-List-Generator/tree/Copy-that-is-not-fully-functioning)

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the slow down are the **Array Formulas**.  They are evaluating millions of extra cells.

> =IFERROR(INDEX($A:$A,SMALL(IF($A:$A<>"",ROW($A:$A)-ROW($A$1)+1),ROW())),"")

By creating 4 **Dynamic Named Ranges** I was able to rework the  **Array Formulas**, so that the Meals post virtually instantaneously.  The workbook also opens much faster.

**New Defined Names:**

- BreakFast_Meal_Name:

  > `=OFFSET(BreakfastSheet!$A$1,1,0,COUNTA(BreakfastSheet!$B:$B)-1,1)`
- Dinner_Meal_Name:

  > `=OFFSET(DinnerSheet!$A$1,1,0,COUNTA(DinnerSheet!$B:$B)-1,1)`
- Lunch_Meal_Names:

  > `=OFFSET(LunchSheet!$A$1,1,0,COUNTA(LunchSheet!$B:$B)-1,1)`
- Snack_Meal_Name:

  > `=OFFSET(SnacksSheet!$A$1,1,0,COUNTA(SnacksSheet!$B:$B)-1,1)`

**New Array Formulas:**

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(BreakFast_Meal_Name,SMALL(IF(BreakFast_Meal_Name<>"",ROW(BreakFast_Meal_Name)-ROW($A$2)+1),ROW())),"")
=IFERROR(INDEX(Lunch_Meal_Names,SMALL(IF(Lunch_Meal_Names<>"",ROW(Lunch_Meal_Names)-ROW($A$2)+1),ROW())),"")
=IFERROR(INDEX(Dinner_Meal_Name,SMALL(IF(Dinner_Meal_Name<>"",ROW(Dinner_Meal_Name)-ROW($A$2)+1),ROW())),"")
=IFERROR(INDEX(Snack_Meal_Name,SMALL(IF(Snack_Meal_Name<>"",ROW(Snack_Meal_Name)-ROW($A$2)+1),ROW())),"")
```

### `AddIngredient_Click:Button Event`

I see no reason for the intermediate variables in `AddIngredient_Click`.  The control names are meaningful enough.  I would prepend TextBox names with `txt`.  I also recommend **Proper Casing** the ingredients when you add them to the Listbox, instead of doing it when you add them to the worksheet

```
Private Sub AddIngredient_Click()
    If NewIngredient.Value = vbNullString Or Not IsNumeric(NewIngredientAmount.Value) Then
        MsgBox "Both Ingredient and Amount are Required Fields", vbInformation, "Try Again"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If Int(NewIngredientAmount.Value) < NewIngredientAmount.Value Then
        MsgBox "Amount can not be less then 0 and Fractions are not Allowed", vbInformation, "Try Again"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    IngredientList.AddItem StrConv(NewIngredient.Value, vbProperCase)
    IngredientList.List(IngredientList.listCount - 1, 1) = NewIngredientAmount.Value
    NewIngredient.Value = vbNullString
    NewIng
```

Comment: When did you become narcissistic? Also, thanks - let me digest this answer

Comment: That array formula stuff is great, the reason it was so convoluted is because my data validation on PlanSheet shows empties otherwise.

Comment: And I'm 100% on board with my button event, it was overthought, thanks

Comment: I've been narcissistic my whole life..lol.

Comment: Yikes. Well, you take criticism pretty well for a narcissist.. The only way I can think of fixing the data validation would be reworking the formulas in a worksheet_change event.

Comment: Your data validation works with the changes that I made.